# Proving $a \in \overline{\{axa : x \in A\}}$ for a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and $a \in A_+$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a problem with the following exercise. Any help is welcome.

$A$ is a $C^*$-algebra and $a \in A_+$. Prove that $a \in \overline{\{axa : x \in A\}}$.

My idea is to use the functional calculus. We can suppose that $A$ is unital.

Then it is équivalent to prove that the identity $id$ on $\sigma(a)$ belongs to $\overline{\{id.f.id : f \in C(\sigma(a))\}}$. where $id(t)f(t)id(t) = t^2f(t)$.

I don't know how I can continue.

Kébir JBIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: Note that $f$ defined by $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ is not an element
of $C_{0}(\sigma(a))$ (and not even well-defined). The idea is, for
each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $f_{n}:\sigma(a)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$
by 
$$
f_{n}(t)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{t}, & \mbox{ if } t\in [\frac{1}{n},\infty)\cap\sigma(a)\\
0, & \mbox{ if } t\in [0,\frac{1}{2n}]\cap\sigma(a)\\
\mbox{linear joining the points }(\frac{1}{2n},0),\,\,(\frac{1}{n},n), & \mbox{ if }t\in(\frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n})\cap \sigma(a)
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f_{n}\in C_{0}(\sigma(a))$. Then prove that $id(t)^{2}f_{n}(t)=t^{2}f_{n}(t)\rightarrow t$
uniformly on $\sigma(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Danny

$a \in A_+$, so the spectrum $\sigma(a) \subset \mathbb R_+$. If $0 \notin \sigma(a)$, $a$ is invertible. Then $a = aa^{-1}a \in \{axa : x \in A\} \subset \overline{\{axa : x \in A\}}$.

Otherwise ($0 \in \sigma(a)$), we use the sequence $(f_n)$ suggested by Danny :

\begin{align}
  f_n(t) = \begin{cases}
    0 \textit{ if } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2n}\\
    2t-\frac{1}{n} \textit{ if } \frac{1}{2n} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
    \frac{1}{t} \textit{ if } t \geq \frac{1}{2n}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}

All these functions are in $C(\sigma(a))$, and one can easily verify that $\sup_{t \in \sigma(a)} |t^2f(t)-t| = \frac{1}{2n}$ which converges to $0$.

Comment: There is a typo about the definition of $f_n(t)$ for the case $\frac{1}{2n} < t < \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thank you again. The right function is \begin{align}
  f_n(t) = \begin{cases}
    0 \textit{ si } 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2n}\\
    2n^2t-n \textit{ si } \frac{1}{2n} \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}\\
    \frac{1}{t} \textit{ si } t \geq \frac{1}{n}
  \end{cases}
\end{align}. The result still unchanged.